# Import Images into a Resource folder at Runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

My Problem is that Players should be able to insert their own images into the game, but they often just ignore the size of the images and then the game is loading 5 MB PNGs, causing a delay in the image display.

using Resources.Load seems to have virtually no delay, no matter the file size. Hence my questions:

Is there any way to import images into a Resource folder during runtime?
Is there a problem with having a Resource folder with 10000+ images, totaling at around 10 GB?

in case you are wondering is going on. I'm making slavemaker4 since the Dev of slavemaker3 is gone for years and we don't have a complete source code.

Comment: I don't think so because resources.assets is built when the player is built

Comment: how are you currently loading the images? maybe we should think about the way you are loading the images instead of thinking where to put them?

Comment: agree with lotan there is likely an efficient way to load these images

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Unity's StreamingAssets folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).

Comment: Thats only a fixed location to keep them. There is sadly no increase in loading speed for the single images. I guess Im just going to have to live with a small loading delay.